# How useCapture and capture in function addEventListener work

Tags: javascript

I'm making simple javascript game. But there something I can't understand in my code. Here is my code:

```
// INIT THE GAME
document.addEventListener( 'load', function() {

    // COUNTDOWN FUNCTION
    var count_down = ( function() {

        // YOU CAN CHANGE THE TIME BY CHANGE TOTAL_TIME
        var total_time  = 3;
        var current_time = total_time;
        var time_element = $( '#time' );
        var count_down_text = $( '#countdown-text' );
        time_element.text( current_time );

        return function() {

            // CREATE A LOOP TO COUNT THE REMAIN TIME 
            var count_down_loop = setInterval( function() {
                current_time = current_time - 1;

                // CHECK FOR REMAIN TIME TO CHANGE QUESTION
                if( current_time < 0 ) {
                    current_time = total_time;
                    if( !change_page( count_down_loop ) ) {
                        clearInterval( count_down_loop );
                        document.dispatchEvent( new Event('game_finish') );
                    }
                }

                time_element.text( current_time );

            }, 1000 );
        }
    } )();

    var change_page = ( function() {

        // YOU CAN CHANGE THE NUMBER OF PAGE BY TOTAL PAGE
        var total_page = 8;
        var current_page = 0;
        var page_element = $( '#card-number-list li a' );
        $( page_element[current_page] ).addClass( 'active' );

        return function() {
            current_page = current_page + 1;
            $( page_element[current_page] ).addClass( 'active' );

            if( current_page < total_page - 1 ){
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    } )();

    document.addEventListener( 'game_start', function() {
        count_down();
        console.log('get event');// Attention to this line.
    });

    document.dispatchEvent( new Event( 'game_start' ) );

}, { capture : true }); //Attention to this line too.
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>JS GAME</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link 
            rel="stylesheet" 
            href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
            integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" 
            crossorigin="anonymous"
        />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- LOADING SCREEN -->
        <div class="loading">
            <div class="loading-container"> 
                <h1>JS GAME</h1>
                <p>LOADING: <span class="loading-value">0</span>%...</p>
                <div class="loading-bar">
                    <div class="loading-bar-current"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- END OF LOADING SCREEN -->

        <!-- GAME SECTION -->
        <div class="game container">
            <div class="card-information row">
                <div class="col-sm-6 push-md-1">
                    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/303x381/000/fff" class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" alt="Responsive image">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 push-md-1">
                    <h3 class="medium-margin-bottom">Card Name:</h3>
                    <h5 class="little-margin-bottom">Card Type: <b>Common</b></h5>
                    <input class="medium-margin-bottom" type="text" />
                    <h5 id="countdown-text" class="medium-margin-bottom">Be Quick!</h5>
                    <div class="countdown">
                        <p id="time"></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-number row">
                <div class="col-sm-11 push-md-1">
                    <p>Just use the numbers on your keyboard to enter the elixir cost</p>
                    <nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
                      <ul id="card-number-list" class="pagination">
                        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">1</a></li>
                        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">2</a></li>
                        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">3</a></li>
                        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">4</a></li>
                        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">5</a></li>
                        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">6</a></li>
                        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">7</a></li>
                        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">8</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- END OF GAME SECTION -->

    </body>
    <script 
        src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" 
        integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" 
        crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script 
        src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" 
        integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" 
        crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script 
        src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" 
        integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" 
        crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script src="js/loading-screen.js"></script>
    <script src ="js/game.js"></script>
</html>
```

if I use the option `{capture : true}` the listener for `load` will show 'get event' 1 time. but if I change `{ capture : true }` to only `true` it will show 'get event' 3 times. Why Does it happen like that? Does `useCapture` different from `capture` in javascript `addEventListener`

Comment: Could you also show the HTML markup ? It seems document's captured load will catch all elements' in doc load events. And while I though I was able to reproduce, its not the case anymore...

Comment: Thanks @Kaiido. I've add html now. But when i change to: `window.addEventListener('load')` it run once. Still don't know why.